# Front end slider

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm trying to create a slider on the front page of my template I have been working on. I have used the Views module to create a block. I have created a custom block for this view.

I am trying to make the posts in the block slide using jQuery coda. I am failing dismally. Has anyone managed to create a working posts slider for drupal 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use views for this otherwise it s going to be more problematic to get your markup right.

Instead make a Databse query to the "node" table, grab all NID that match your node type and load them:

```
      $nodes = array();
      $nids = db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = :type',
 array(':type' =>YOUR_NODE_TYPE))->fetchCol();
      if (!empty($nids)) {
        $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);    
      }
      return $nodes;
```

Then pass these nodes to your page using a page preprocess function.

Finally override the template page for your node type: `node--YOUR_NODE_TYPE.tpl.php,` and there you should have your nodes available in that page (in an arbitrary variable name that your defined in the preprocess function `$variables['my_bunch_of_node']=...`). You just need to loop through them so that the content fits exactly the original markup required by your script.

Oh and also don't forget to add your .JS , either via the .info file, either via drupal_add_js (in the page preprocess function)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have views used the views module. With it i managed to create a block. I them used jquery to animate the contents. It's working fine. It's my first drupal site and i am impresses at the progress. :)

Comment: Good to hear, if you know JS better than drupal, that was the way to go.